# Finding the album of a song

Tags: echonest

I've been playing around with Echonest, but can't seem to figure out how to get the album of a song (given I have the artist name and the song). I'd also like to find the genre and the album cover. Or are these things I'd have to use foreign ID spaces for (Rosetta Stone)?

Honestly, it'd be nice if I could punch in the artist name and title and get a summary of information about the song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this: 
http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/song.html#search

you should provide your title and artist name to the search api possibly with an external id like id:7digital or id:spotify since echonest does not give you album information directly. I guess most of the cases you can find foreign release id for spotify album and get the release information about it from spotify. Instead, you can skip echonest api and directly make your searches in spotify API.